# Ternary operator evaluation order with mean of empty list

Tags: python, numpy, ternary-operator, mean

```
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> mylist = []
>>> mean(mylist) if mylist is not [] else None
nan
```

I thought the test was supposed to be evaluated first in the ternary operator. I expected `None`. Why did I get `nan` instead?

**Edit:** Why wouldn't an empty list be identically the same as `[]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The test

```
mylist is not []
```

does not check if `mylist` is empty.  It checks if it is identically the same object as another empty list.

You should just use:

```
mean(mylist) if mylist else None
```

Comment: Why wouldn't an empty list be identically the same as []?

Comment: In fact `mylist is not []` will always be `True`. Any new list is distinct from any existing list.

Comment: @Hatshepsut: why *would* they be the same?  The fact that two bags are both empty doesn't mean they're actually the same bag.

Comment: @DSM That's cool. What is the attribute of the two lists that is being compared (and is not equal)?

Comment: @donkopotamus: The use-case here is obviously lists, but `numpy.mean` also works fine in the trivial case of a scalar (e.g. `mean(5.0)` returns 5.0).  If that is also a potential use-case here, then there is a bug, because `mean(x) if x else None` returns `None` if `x` is 0 (0 is interpreted as False).

Comment: @Hatshepsut Just their identity. That's because there are "basic" values like numbers where their actual values are compared, and "complex" values like lists which are compared just by asking "is this thing the same as that thing" and not "it this thing's value the same as that thing's" (because it might be impossible, very slow or ambigous to define the value). `0 is not 0` will be false, but `[] is not []` will be true.